# Appcompat / add a library with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

**[Fixed] When you have added your dependencies you need to sync your project. It's the icon on the left of AVD Manager icon**

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to use the appcompat-v7 with android studio.
I add those lines:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

In the build.gradle but when I try to import the lib:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

It says me that cannot resolve v7 .. And when I check the folder external lib there is only support-v4.

Did I miss something ?

Ps: It worked in an other project and I could see the lib in external lib but it don't want do it again ..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should have two dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

Verify that you have downloaded the latest Android Support Library and Support Repository within your SDK manager.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download

Detailed tutorial on setting up the ActionBarActivity:

http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2013/08/14/actionbar-with-android-support-library-r18/

Comment: Thanks for reply! Well yea that's what I did. And I can found the libraries here AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support.Maybe should I add them manually ?

Comment: @nsvir: I'm glad you fixed it. I have the same problem right now and would be very glad if you'd tell me (and the rest of the world) how you fixed it?!

Comment: You need to sync your project :) Look at my post

Answer (score 1):

To add on blackcj Avoid using + in versions numbers it can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds on android studio this may lead to more build time by gradle. Thats expensive!