# android studio - Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to migrate from **Eclipse** to **Android studio** for android app development. But having hard time configuring it.

Extracting downloaded android-studio I put it to `/usr/local`. Then created a new project. But 
following imports are not recognised.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

[image: symbol not recognised]

#### My app structure is

```
Add2Wallet/
├── Add2Wallet
│   ├── Add2Wallet-Add2Wallet.iml
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── proguard-rules.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│           ├── ic_launcher-web.png
│           ├── java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── zazzercode
│           │           └── add2wallet
│           │               └── Add2WalletView.java
│           └── res
│               ├── drawable-hdpi
│               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│               ├── drawable-mdpi
│               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│               ├── drawable-xhdpi
│               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│               ├── drawable-xxhdpi
│               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│               ├── layout
│               │   ├── activity_add2_wallet_view.xml
│               │   └── fragment_add2_wallet_view.xml
│               ├── menu
│               │   └── add2_wallet_view.xml
│               ├── values
│               │   ├── dimens.xml
│               │   ├── strings.xml
│               │   └── styles.xml
│               └── values-w820dp
│                   └── dimens.xml
├── Add2Wallet.iml
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local.properties
└── settings.gradle
```

#### local.properties is

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/usr/local/android-studio/sdk
```

#### The default build.gradle is

```
  1 buildscript {
  2     repositories {
  3         mavenCentral()
  4     }
  5     dependencies {
  6         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  7     }
  8 }
  9 apply plugin: 'android'
 10 
 11 repositories {
 12     mavenCentral()
 13 }
 14 
 15 android {
 16     compileSdkVersion 19
 17     buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
 18 
 19     defaultConfig {
 20         minSdkVersion 7
 21         targetSdkVersion 19
 22         versionCode 1
 23         versionName "1.0"
 24     }
 25     buildTypes {
 26         release {
 27             runProguard false
 28             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
 29         }
 30     }
 31 }
 32 
 33 dependencies {
 34     //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
 35     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
 36 }
```

Found similar problem at [Appcompat / add a library with android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18364135/432903) but solution `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'` provided there doesn't work for me.

On `$ gradlew build`, I get following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/backup/workspace.programming/workspace.android/Add2Wallet/Add2Wallet/build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Add2Wallet'.
> org/gradle/tooling/provider/model/ToolingModelBuilderRegistry

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Another issue is that When I hit `Sync Project with Gradle files` in **android-studio**, I get following error

```
23:08:10 ExternalSystemException
         Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.
         Unable to start the daemon process.
         This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
         For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
         Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
         Please read below process output to find out more:
         -----------------------
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: cannot create 7���libpthread.so.0_Jv_RegisterClasseslibjli.so__gmon_start__JLI_Launchlibdl.so.2libc.so.6__libc_start_mainlib.so/../lib/amd64/jli:/../jre/lib/amd64/jliSUNWprivate_1.1GLIBC_2.2.5�U/pq�N�%: Directory nonexistent
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: ELF: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 3: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
         : Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.
         Unable to start the daemon process.
         This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
         For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
         Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
         Please read below process output to find out more:
         -----------------------
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: cannot create 7���libpthread.so.0_Jv_RegisterClasseslibjli.so__gmon_start__JLI_Launchlibdl.so.2libc.so.6__libc_start_mainlib.so/../lib/amd64/jli:/../jre/lib/amd64/jliSUNWprivate_1.1GLIBC_2.2.5�U/pq�N�%: Directory nonexistent
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: ELF: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 3: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: �: not found
         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: 1: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

23:08:11 Gradle invocation completed successfully in 0 sec
```

Comment: You've got weird things going on in your Java installation: look at the nature of the errors in your Gradle sync output.

Answer (score 1):

It seems V7 depends on V4 support.You can not use V7 only.
And checked your android support library is the newest?