# Android Studio; Launching to USB Device (phone), installs but won't open

Tags: java, android

My application builds and says successful, but exits without launching when I open it on my phone. Is there something wrong with my manifest file?

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.terik.thirdattempt/com.example.terik.thirdattempt.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.widget.Button

Here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.terik.thirdattempt" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my layout for kicks and giggles.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="72pt"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Button1"></TextView>

 <Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And I guess my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.terik.thirdattempt;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
int number = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void addOne(View view){
    number = number +1;
    textView.setText(number);
}

}
```

Comment: are you using logcat?

Comment: Yes, and I just posted the report above (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got null pointer exception because you declare your textview before setcontent view. This should fix that (but i dont understand what method addOne is, so i leave that alone):

```
int number = 0;
TextView textView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void addOne(View view){
    number = number +1;
    textView.setText(number);
}
```

Comment: I was sure this was right. But it still won't launch :(

Comment: I'm getting Exception = {java.lang.ClassNotFoundException@830050032376}
name = {java.lang.String@830050032240}"android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$Callback"

Comment: how do you import that library? do you just put the jar in your project? maybe you can read [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364135/appcompat-add-a-library-with-android-studio)

Comment: What library? I may not have imported a library... do I need to?

Comment: Now the logcat says this
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.terik.thirdattempt/com.example.terik.thirdattempt.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.widget.Button

Comment: Turns out my button .png file was too big. It was a memory exception.

Comment: ooh. then accept my answer if i help your problem ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize UI after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in the function of onCreate.

So your app crashed when you launched your device.You Should initialize the TextView after the function of onCreate like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```