# cannt import v7 library

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, appcompatactivity

I want to know why my Android studio Cannot resolve AppCompactActivity symbol, when I try to add the AppCompat v7 library This import statement

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

shows up with gray color and says unused import statement 
and v7 with red color and says Cannot resolve symbol'v7'

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

  public class speech extends AppCompatActivity
```

build.grade:

```
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${androidSupportLibraryVersion}"
compile 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.18'
compile 'de.cketti.library.changelog:ckchangelog:1.2.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.7'
compile 'de.cketti.safecontentresolver:safe-content-resolver-v14:0.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.2.0'
compile "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${timberVersion}"

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}"
testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
testCompile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appcompat / add a library with android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364135/appcompat-add-a-library-with-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add AppCompat Library in Gradel file.

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${androidSupportLibraryVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportLibraryVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${androidSupportLibraryVersion}"
```

**Sometimes clearing the android studio caches help.**

In android studio I just cleared the caches and restarted with the following option--

```
File->Invalidate Caches/Restart
```